# Setting up permissions for a  multilingual joomla site

Tags: joomla, joomla1.7, joomla-component

I'm building a multilingual joomla 1.7 website that will have to support up to 25 countries with each country being a website on its own, the site will be managed by different teams for each country, basically what i'm trying to achieve is, setting up the permissions system so that each team can only see content that belong to its country. now, i'm wondering how to achieve this in the following cases:
1. setting the permissions for standard joomla articles...may be using categories??
2.since i have coded a custom component for managing products on the site, how to implement the permissions in my own component.....

it's easy to implement the multilingual feature on the front-end but how about the backend in terms of access control?

any ideas, thoughts would be greatly appreciated :)
Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have resolved your problem earlier but may be somebody else needs help on this.

First of all you have to create a User groups for every country (or a couple for 
start, example Ireland, England).

Then you have to create a AccessLevels groups for those groups and set (select) 
corresponding usergroup on it (e. ACL_Ireland / Ireland, ACL_England / England).

Then you can create a top level category for every country (ACL_Ireland, ACL_England, ...)
Users of other countries are not able to see top and sublevel categories if you set the category permission for single ACL and deny access from others.

Move to Category manager and create top level category for country Ireland.
Name it like "Ireland".
Set it permission for ACL_Ireland.
Remove all permissions from other country ACL's.
Save & close category.

Select the category from list of categories.
Select *Add to root*, *Copy* under *Batch process the selected categories* and click *Process*.

Category is copied as a new entry on category list.
Open category as editing and change name as England, save and close.
Select category England, **ACL_England** from *Batch process the selected 
categories* and click *Process*.

Category England now have different acl-rights and can be accessed only by users in England - group.

Articles created in those categories are inherited permissions from top level category 
so you are not needed to give persmissions on single articles.

Repeat this to categories of all needed countries and ACL's.

You have to also restrict access from those acl's to **Users component** because theycan be else change permissions by themself and see documents of other coutries.

It is necessary to design the accessing model before implementing it because it could be heady job to change permissons to all goups and acl's later.